# polygon in polygon in polygon(or more...)

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-script-tool

[image]

I have a buildings feature class which contains a building in a building (4 times), and I want to extract each building to a new feature class which  created. I have written a Python code that does half what I want.

1. it creates a new field (count in)
2. it makes a feature class
3. selection by location and then by attribute
4. creates a new feature class for results
5. count

I want that script extract the single building and give them the number 1 in "count_ in" field, and then copy the row to the new fc(fc_1).
then extract the building in building and give the number 2 to the feature class which selected, and copy to the new fc(fc_2).
exactly to the other feature (3 bldg and 4 bldg).

this is the code:

```
#this script selected(by location)bldg in bldg, and print the result by 1 or 2
#or 3 (or more)in a new field("count_in")if was select bldg in bldg.


print "Start"

import time
import arcpy
from time import strftime

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = 1

FC_BLDG = r"D:\AVI_DAVID\DB_CORRECTION_TEST\test.gdb\poly_test"
gdb_name = "bldg_in_bldg_check"+'_'+strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")#
GDB_Destination = r"D:\AVI_DAVID\DB_CORRECTION_TEST"#
GDB = arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(GDB_Destination,gdb_name+'_'+strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")) #create gdb+location



count = arcpy.GetCount_management(FC_BLDG)
for con in count:
        print con ," TOTAL bldg COUNT"
        print""
        print""

##fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(FC_BLDG)
##fieldListName=[]
##for field in fieldList:
##    fieldListName.append(field.name)
##    if "count_in" not in fieldListName:
##        arcpy.AddField_management(FC_BLDG,"count_in")
##        arcpy.CalculateField_management(FC_BLDG,"count_in","1")


def count_inside(FC_BLDG,c):

    fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(FC_BLDG)
    fieldListName=[]
    for field in fieldList:
        fieldListName.append(field.name)
    if "count_in" not in fieldListName:
        arcpy.AddField_management(FC_BLDG,"count_in")




    if c == 1:
        exp = '"count_in" IS NULL'
    else:
        exp = '"count_in" IS NOT NULL'


    lyr1= arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC_BLDG,"lyr1",exp)
    lyr2= arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(FC_BLDG,"lyr2",exp)


    print "count features before selection",arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr1)

    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(lyr1,"COMPLETELY_WITHIN",lyr2, "","NEW_SELECTION")

    NEW = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(GDB,"BLDG"+str(c),"POLYGON",FC_BLDG)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(lyr1,NEW)


    try:
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(lyr1,"count_in",c)
    except:
        print arcpy.GetMessages(2)

    print "count features after selection",arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr1)
    return arcpy.GetCount_management(lyr1)



c=1
count_inside(FC_BLDG,c)

c=2
count_inside(FC_BLDG,c)

c=3
count_inside(FC_BLDG,c)

c=4
count_inside(FC_BLDG,c)



print "-------OK-------"
```

Comment: Your question is very difficult ro read With Every Word Capitalized. Please [Edit] it to follow proper English usage.

Comment: I agree with @Vince your question is very difficult to read.  Please [edit] your question so that not every word is capitalized which will make it easier to read and understand what you are asking.

Comment: The feature class also contain buildings that have no building inside them and you dont want to export these? If not then it is easy to create a new fc from each feature

Comment: Yes. there are buildings without building, which mean-  single.
those that contain single building will have the number 1 in "count_in" field.
rest of the building will have 2,3,4 …. depending on what it contains

Answer (score 1):

This is quick and dirty.  This script works for me on getting the counts of parcels "COMPLETELY_WITHIN".  It adds the field if it doesn't exist and goes though each row in the polygon fc and updates the "count_in" field no matter if it is NULL or NOT.  You could esily add an if statement after the select by attribute and test if row[1] is null.  Im also not sure if the select by location method "COMPLETELY_WITHIN" is what you wanted. Hope this helps

```
import arcpy

path = r"Connection\To\FC"

#layer names
parcels = "parcels"
parcelsSelected = "parcelsSelected"

#feature layers
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path, parcels)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(path, parcelsSelected)

fieldNames = [field.name for field in arcpy.ListFields(parcels)]
if "count_in" not in fieldNames:
    print "adding 'count_in' field"
    arcpy.AddField_management(parcels,"count_in","SHORT")
else:
    print "count_in field already exists"

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(parcels,['OBJECTID','count_in']) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        where_clause = "OBJECTID = {0}".format(row[0])
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(parcels, "NEW_SELECTION", where_clause)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(parcelsSelected, "COMPLETELY_WITHIN", parcels, "", "NEW_SELECTION", "NOT_INVERT")
        c_child = arcpy.GetCount_management(parcelsSelected)
        print "OBJECTID: {0}, # of Parcels Within: {1}".format(row[0],c_child)
        row[1] = int(c_child.getOutput(0)) + 1 #+1 to count the selected feature itself
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I try to set it up with my data (change names- that all), and it's just give the number by order 1,2,3… in "count_in" field.
There is no really buildings extracting